# Different ht-password protection for each subfolder and removing existing protection from parent folder

Tags: .htaccess, apache2, password-protection

I have linked folder which is htaccess password protected from its parent folder, this protection in parent folder needs to stay and cannot be easily changed due upload scripts. I need that linked uploads folder to have couple subfolders with different username/password for each using .htaccess.

Example:

```
/media/scripts/uploads => /data/uploads < linked folder
/media/scripts/.htaccess < password protected folder
/data/uploads/subfolder1 username1
/data/uploads/subfolder2 username2
/data/uploads/subfolder3 username3
```

Problem is that /data/uploads folder needs to be password free and if possible show those 3 subfolders (thou could make index.html file for links). I can get 3 different passwords working for 3 subfolders, but /data/uploads folder keeps asking the password for /media/scripts folder (the parent folder).

How I can disable password protection in parent directory while keeping it in subfolders when parent's parent folder has a password protection?

I tried using Satisfy Any on uploads folder, but it removes protection on subfolders too.